# Which integer am I mistaking for an array? ('int' object has no attribute '__getitem__')

Tags: python, runtime-error

I get the error in python that

`TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

I know that this means that somewhere I am applying apply the index operator `[]` on an int and not a list, but I don't know where?

```py
def p1(p,a,b):
    result1=1
    result2=1
    for i in np.arange(0,p-1):
        result1=result1*Tarray[i]
    for i in np.arange(p,147):
        result2=result2*Tarray[i]
    return np.sum(result1[n,a]*Tarray[p-1][a,b]*result2[b,m] for n in range(4) for m in range(4))

u=np.arange(1,4)
Pro=np.vectorize(p1)

print Pro(u,0,0)
```

Here `Tarray` is an array of 147 numerical 4x4-matrices.

The odd thing is that when I plug in a numerical value for p, the `p1` works perfectly fine.

EDIT:
The full error code is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-469d01d2eef0> in <module>()
     11 Pro=np.vectorize(p1)
     12 
---> 13 print Pro(u,0,0)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1698             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
   1699 
-> 1700         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
   1701 
   1702     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.pyc in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   1761             _res = func()
   1762         else:
-> 1763             ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
   1764 
   1765             # Convert args to object arrays first

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.pyc in _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args)
   1723             # arrays (the input values are not checked to ensure this)
   1724             inputs = [asarray(_a).flat[0] for _a in args]
-> 1725             outputs = func(*inputs)
   1726 
   1727             # Performance note: profiling indicates that -- for simple

<ipython-input-51-469d01d2eef0> in p1(p, a, b)
      6     for i in np.arange(p,147):
      7         result2=result2*Tarray[i]
----> 8     return np.sum(result1[n,a]*Tarray[p-1][a,b]*result2[b,m] for n in range(4) for m in range(4))
      9 
     10 u=np.arange(1,4)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.pyc in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   1707     """
   1708     if isinstance(a, _gentype):
-> 1709         res = _sum_(a)
   1710         if out is not None:
   1711             out[...] = res

<ipython-input-51-469d01d2eef0> in <genexpr>((n,))
      6     for i in np.arange(p,147):
      7         result2=result2*Tarray[i]
----> 8     return np.sum(result1[n,a]*Tarray[p-1][a,b]*result2[b,m] for n in range(4) for m in range(4))
      9 
     10 u=np.arange(1,4)

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question. And add a comment in your code where the stack trace mentions your code.

Comment: you need to include code that defines `Tarray` or no one can really help you

Comment: Try 1) look at the line number given in the error message; 2) removing things until your program works ("divide and conquer")

Comment: Hi, first time poster here. Thanks for the remarks, I will change my question. But no need for the downvote...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What is a stack trace?

Comment: @PaulH ```Tarray``` is a numpy array of 147 numerical 4x4-matrices, so all of them are just filled with numbers

Comment: @chelmertz The error is in the line ```return np.sum(result1[n,a]*Tarray[p-1][a,b]*result2[b,m] for n in range(4) for m in range(4))```, for example if I remove the summation over ```n``` and ```m``` and just sum over the elements of the product of the matrices (which however does not do what I want), it does work. So the line```return np.sum(result1*Tarray[p-1][a,b]*result2)``` would work (but again is not the same as what I want)

Comment: If p=1, the first loop `for i in np.arange(0,p-1):`  doesn't run, so `result1` is still the integer 1 when you try to  access `result1[n,a]` in your sum.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Ah indeed that was it! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @RobertS.Pierre the trigger fingers of some users are fast, and historically many great questions were closed as non-objective so.. it's nothing personal :/ Have an upvote!

Comment: @RobertS.Pierre Since you're asking others to help you free of charge, the onus yours to make it as easy as possible for people to run your code and reproduce the error. Since Tarray was only described, but not defined, you kind of missed that mark. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example